# Is there a multi-column listbox widget in FLTK?

Tags: user-interface, listbox, cross-platform, widget, fltk

I'm evaluating cross-platform GUI toolkits for C++ development. I already use Qt but in this case the LGPL is too restrictive (I need to link statically).

Now FLTK would be an excellent library for my purposes, because it seems to be fast and lightweight. However, I haven't been able to figure out whether it has a multi-column listbox widget. You know, one of those grids with rows and columns of strings and headers that can be clicked to sort a column---preferably all with a native look-and-feel.

Is there such a thing in FLTK? How is it called? Or should I use wxWidgets instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fl_Table.  It comes with the 1.3 release candidate.  There is an example in 1.3 /test of a sortable table that I have modified and used.  It feels a lot lower level than QT but you can do anything with it.  Also, if you look close parts of wxWidgets has licensing similar to QT.

Table.html">http://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/classFl_Table.html